# Kivy: How to update an image on a screen?

Tags: python, image, raspberry-pi, kivy, reload

Hello, I am currently creating a GUI using kivy, on Windows. I am using it to ssh into a Raspberry Pi, take an image, then scp it back to my windows machine. I have successfully done this using the GUI. I have two screens. The first is the login. Once I login a second screen appears with buttons and an image. The login screen and buttons serve their functions properly. However, the image file does not update like I want it to. Either I want it to update in a certain interval, or update after I take a picture.

Here is the
[Second Screen Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ewya6.png). I want the picture on the top right to update itself automatically. The "take picture" button takes the picture then sends it to my computer where I'd like to refresh the image in the GUI and display it

My main python file, which I called "ScreenChange2.py" is shown below

```
import kivy
import os

kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from sshtest import ssh #import the ssh class from the ssh python file


class ScreenOne(Screen):
    def login(self): #define login using ssh as a function

        #Make a Class Variable called connection. This allows for other
        #classes to call on it without passing it as an argument

        ScreenOne.connection = ssh("192.168.1.3", "pi", "seniordesign")
                #ScreenOne.connection.sendCommand("ls")
        #ScreenOne.connection.sendCommand("mkdir thisistest")
        print("Logging in") #For error checking

    def gpioSet(self): #allows for gpio pins to trigger image capture
        ScreenOne.connection.sendCommand("echo '18' > /sys/class/gpio/export")
        ScreenOne.connection.sendCommand("echo 'out' > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/direction")

class ScreenTwo(Screen): #This is where all the functions are

    def command(self, input): #create a function that sends command through ssh
        ScreenOne.connection.sendCommand(input) #Call on connection made before to send command


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


#Create the Application that will change screens. Add App(App) to end of wanted classname
class ScreenChangeApp(App):

#Create a function that builds the app. Keyword self make sures to reference
#current instantiation

    def build(self):
        screen_manager = ScreenManager()

        screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenOne(name = "screen_one")) 
        screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenTwo(name = "screen_two"))

        return screen_manager #after building the screens, return them
#MyScreenManager.login()

sample_app = ScreenChangeApp()
sample_app.run()
```

The KV file is as shown

```
#: import os os
<CustomButton@Button>:
    font_size: 12
    size_hint: .2,.1

<Picture@Image>:
    id: image

<ScreenOne>: #define The First Screen
    BoxLayout: #Use box layout
        Button: #create button
            text: "Connect to the Raspberry Pi"
            on_press:
                root.login()
                root.gpioSet()
                root.manager.transition.direction= "left"
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = "screen_two"

<ScreenTwo>:
    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        padding: 10
        orientation: "vertical"
        CustomButton:
            text: "Send an ls command"
            on_press:
                root.command("ls")

        CustomButton:
            text: "Take picture"
            on_press:
                root.command("python cameradaemon.py &") #'&' runs script in background
                root.command("sleep .1")
                root.command("echo '1' > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value") #set pin high to take pic
                root.command("echo '0' > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value") #take it off to prevent another photo 

                root.command("scp TEST.jpg Jason@192.168.1.10:C:/Users/Jason/Desktop/RaspberryPiTransferred")          
                root.command("kill %1")

        CustomButton:
            text: "Create Histogram"
            on_press:
                os.system("cd C:/Users/Jason/Desktop/KivyFiles/Histogram & python histogram.py")


    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'right'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        padding: 10

        BoxLayout
            size_hint: .3, .3
            Image:
                source: 'C:/Users/Jason/Desktop/RaspberryPiTransferred/TEST.jpg'
```

As you can probably tell, at the end of the KV file, I insert the image file in a box layout as static. I understand this is why my image won't update, but what I need to know is how I can update it automatically.

I was thinking I could maybe make a custom picture rule, which I started at the top as

```
<Picture@Image>:
```

I also understand there is a Reload() function for image files, but I do not understand how to implement that in a KV file.

I've tried creating a class in my main file that runs the reload function every second, but the image doesn't display as it isn't linked to any image in the KV file.

In other words, how do I make it so that the image being displayed in this [Second Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUqIv.png) to update automatically given the two scripts I've given. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your ScreenTwo class create a StringProperty at the class level:

```
class ScreenTwo(Screen): #This is where all the functions are
    img_src = StringProperty('C:/Users/Jason/Desktop/RaspberryPiTransferred/TEST.jpg')

    def command(self, input):
```

And in your kv file reference it by:

```
        Image:
            source: root.img_src
```

Then change the image just by doing:

```
img_src = 'some/new/image.jpg'
```

The image should update without any further actions needed.

Comment: This seems like a good solution, but what happens if I want to reload that specific image? For example, my code takes and replaces the image file named TEST.jpg.

Will I be able to constantly update that image automatically while the GUI is running?

Comment: @Jason, yes, you should be able to update as often as you wish.

Comment: I may be a little confused. It is not updating. The only time it updates is if I exit the GUI interface and start it again.

I need to be able to update it through code without user input either. It seems as though I'm not understanding what you're saying. I added the 'img_src' as a string property and i changed by kv file to reflect that, but every time I run the GUI it shows the previous picture, then when I take a new picture it doesn't update

Comment: @Jason, When you take a new picture, you need to set `img_src` to the new file: `img_src = 'C:/some/new/image.jpg'`. When you restart your GUI,  it will start with whatever image you have hard-coded into it (in this case the TEST.jpg). If you want the app to remember the changes you make, then you should look at kivy.config.

Comment: Right, what I'm looking for is a dynamic update. I need the picture to update dynamically, I do not want a static image. Imagine everytime I take the image it updates to whatever the new image is

Answer (score 0):

```
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.image.html
reload()
im = Image(source = '1.jpg')
# -- do something --
im.reload()
# image will be re-loaded from disk
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**